# What does "Plays pretty just for you" (a song's title) mean?

Tags: meaning

Should it be understood as "(He) plays, darling, only for you"?

Comment: I'm afraid interpreting song-lyrics is off topic in EL & U. But I would say it might be deliberately ambiguous. It's impossible to know without the context.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the song, but, if I were to venture a guess, I'd assume it either means (a) he is faithful, or (b) he gives his best effort only to one person. I'd have recommended at least adding a link to the lyrics, to make this easier to answer, but that's moot: As Urbycoz said, lyric interpretation is off-topic. (At first, that may seem overly restrictive, but, if you think about it, lyrics are poems written by musicians, so there's really no way to say for sure what someone "means." If you could find the same expression used in a news story, though, that might change things.)

Comment: Please add context in the question itself, rather than merely in comments in replies to answers. -1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is in regard to the [Jimmy Smith's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plays_Pretty_Just_for_You) *Plays Pretty Just for You*, **plays pretty** is just that -- he doesn't pound the organ keys senselessly, he pours his soul into each note with *you* in mind.

Comment: BRAVO! Your guess is right: it's J.S.

Comment: @all: there is no any lyrics, only the title!

Comment: I'm happy to have helped!

Comment: :-) P.S. I'm a fan of J.S. & Hammond B-3 + Leslie's loudspeakers.

Comment: @trg787: If there are no lyrics, only a title, you could have said that – at least mention that it's an instrumental.

Comment: @J.R., I'd mention it but I don't know how it (no lyrics) goes in English - composition? track #3? album's title? I didn't think it matters.

Comment: @trg787: not a big deal for this question, now that the problem is solved, but it might be something to keep in mind for next time. It's generally best (and I think "courteous" as well) to provide lots of background information up front, so to save anyone wanting to research your question from doing the same Googles and lookups. In this case, a simple, parenthetical _"This is the title to an instrumental jazz song by keyboardist Jimmy Smith"_ would have provided a wealth of information. You don't need to write a book, but something a bit more than _"What does X mean?"_ is usually appreciated.

Comment: Russian lang is much closer to Sanscrit than to any other language. Comp. (fire)-Ogon'-Agni or (to know)-Vedat'-Vedes or (yoke)-Yigo-Yoga. Or e.g. consider "true" Russian word "kadka" (wooden keg) - actually "kadka" is a Sanscrit word and it came to here from ancient India.

Comment: @J.R., to some extent you're right but English is not my mom tongue.

Comment: @trg787: No worries. It needn't be perfect; just make the effort, and we'll all appreciate it. I'm not trying to be critical, merely helpful. Hopefully, you'll stick around more than a few weeks, and the hints I've tried to give here will help you write better questions in the future. If that happens, everyone wins. P.S. Maybe I'll by this song on iTunes tonight  :^)

Comment: @trg787 The Leslie was a fantastic innovation.  If you like guitar at all, check out [Grant Green](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=grant+green&oq=grant+green&gs_l=youtube.3..0l10.3686.3686.0.3829.1.1.0.0.0.0.118.118.0j1.1.0...0.0.7Brsl4QpZcM) and [Charlie Christian](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=charlie+christian&oq=charlie+christian&gs_l=youtube.3..0l10.2587.6653.0.6900.26.18.2.5.5.1.190.2085.7j11.18.0...0.0.ap_0maTb-kA).  :)

Comment: @J.R., I don't like this album by J.S. It seems to me too sweety. I like from him smth like "Got My Mojo Working".

Comment: @cornbread ninja - OK :) Guys, I'm going to foodshop - my cats are extremely hungry (and me too). Cheers!

Comment: @cornbread ninja, I'm back! The cats are fed up! Bought the cheapest... smth made from pig's liver/internals. In German it's the zeltz. I think Russians copied/stole this word from German language. Actually I'm not a Russian, I'm a Biyelo-Russian. Means White Russian. But in fact they are the same beasts. Absolutely no difference. I don't know my language, of cours, I know it, but I'm stressed while reading smth written in it. But BieloRussian lang is even more ancient than Russian.

Comment: Let's consider name Medvedev. What is "medved"? "Medved" is equal to "bear". What is "med"? It's "honey". Next, "ved" means "to know". I.e., "medved" means the animal that knows where honey is or where it (the animal) can find it (the honey). But "ved" in here is absolutely the same word as in Sanscrit.